# What are the correct ratios for eggless mayonnaise?

Tags: mayonnaise

What is the correct ratio of milk, oil and vinegar to make egg-less mayonnaise?

Comment: Why does this read suspiciously like a recipe request?

Comment: @Stephie : it could also be an attempt to troll for a lawsuit.  For context, see http://www.slate.com/blogs/moneybox/2015/10/23/american_egg_board_ceo_joanne_ivy_resigns_over_eggless_just_mayo_controversy.html

Comment: @stephie We allow questions which are about the correct ratio or ratio range, as opposed to a straight recipe. They are quite answerable for many foods. And for foods where there is no technological reason to use a specific ratio, "as much as you like" is also seen as a valid answer. This is different from suggesting a favorite recipes and readers having to vote each of them.

Comment: @rumtscho That's why I didn't VTC straight away - I was hoping that OP would narrow down the question to a slightly more specific question. There are many recepies available online for egg-less mayo baded on the given ingredients. A "came out too runny" or "is more or less X better for Y" gives us more to work from.

Comment: Just edit the question so it asks for a mayonnaise substitute.

Answer (score 1):

My go to ratio for eggless mayo: 1 cup oil, 1/2 cup full fat milk, 2 tbsp vinegar or lemon juice. You can adjust the taste with other seasonings.

Comment: That sounds about right, 2:1 oil:mayo ratio is also what I use.