# What emulsifier can be used for an Egg-free mayonnaise?

Tags: substitutions, mayonnaise

What emulsifier can be used for an egg-free mayonnaise?

Comment: Lecithin would be typical.

Answer (score 2):

Aquafaba! (also known as chickpea water) Here's a good recipe from Serious Eats:

https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2016/03/easy-vegan-mayo-aquafaba-recipe-vegan-experience.html

Comment: That's a good tip, thanks. The recipe mentions a shelf life of one week, do you think it is reliable?

Answer (score 1):

I've made successful batches of mayo with milk instead of eggs as per this question:
 [What are the correct ratios for eggless mayonnaise?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64389/what-are-the-correct-ratios-for-eggless-mayonnaise?rq=1)